# Posts in sidebar only by admin

Tags: admin, sidebar, user-roles

I want to show in latest posts widget only posts by admin (now its showing latests posts by all suers). How I can do it ? via wp query ? Thanks :)

```
<?php // setup the query
                    $args='&posts_per_page='.$numreviews.'_reviews&order=DESC&orderby='.$feedsort.$metakey;                             
                    $cust_loop = new WP_Query($args); 
                    if ($cust_loop->have_posts()) : while ($cust_loop->have_posts()) : $cust_loop->the_post(); $postcount++;
                        // if we're sorting by rating and this item does not have a rating, hide it
                        $rating = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "Rating", $single = true); 
                        if(($rating && $feedsort=="meta_value") || ($feedsort!="meta_value")) {                                     
                            $ratings = con_setup_rating($rating); //setup the ratings array


                        ?>
                        <li>                                                                                    

                            <?php con_show_rating($ratings[0], $ratings[1], $ratings[2]); // show the stars or hearts ?>    

                            <a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>                                              

                        </li>

                    <?php } ?>

                <?php endwhile; 
                endif; 
                wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [add an author parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters) to the query that is creating `$cust_loop`. You didn't post that part of your code but something like:

```
$cust_loop = new WP_Query( 'author=123' );
```

Or:

```
$cust_loop = new WP_Query( 'author_name=rami' );
```

Note: Both of those taken (almost) straight from the Codex paged for [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters).

Comment: Thanks :) It worked, but there is problem. I had settings that only 6 posts show in sidebar, but when I insert $cust_loop = new WP_Query( 'author=123' ); and widget settings don't work anymore. Now it shows 9 posts, but i want 6 :D

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks now its working :)

```
$cust_loop = new WP_Query(array('author_name' => 'admin', 'posts_per_page' => 6));
```